# Check is url is valid by using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I'd like to create a tool to check if an url is valid (valid: it returns a 200). I have two examples of check in pages of airlines, and both works correctly in the browser. However the British Airlines always throws an exception becuase of a 500 response. What is wrong with my code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testUrl1 = new Program().UrlIsValid("https://www.klm.com/ams/checkin/web/kl/nl/nl");
        var testUrl2 = new Program().UrlIsValid("https://www.britishairways.com/travel/olcilandingpageauthreq/public/en_gb");
        Console.WriteLine(testUrl1 + "\t - https://www.klm.com/ams/checkin/web/kl/nl/nl");
        Console.WriteLine(testUrl2 + "\t - https://www.britishairways.com/travel/olcilandingpageauthreq/public/en_gb");
    }

    public bool UrlIsValid(string onlineCheckInUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(onlineCheckInUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 500 is a server-side response code. Check if further information is provided in the response.

Comment: Use OPTIONS and see the available APIs and then you can use HEAD or TRACE depending on the need.

Comment: How often do you want to issue these requests? I'm asking it because some sites utilize some rate limiting logic to avoid DOS attacks. So, if the frequency is too high then you can be throttled.

Comment: As a side note: Url validity has nothing to do with availability. Please try to use better naming, because the current one is misleading. (`Uri.TryCreate` and `Uri,IsWellFormedUriString` are built-in functionalities to determine the validity)

Comment: @PeterCsala I'd like to issue this request just once per 24h. And I agree with you, it shoul be availability, and not validity.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of sites block obvious bot activity. The British Airways url you show works for me if I set a valid User-Agent request header:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0";
```

Keep in mind that 200 OK is not the only response that means the URL is valid and your method of testing will always be unreliable at best. You may have to narrow your definition of what a valid URL means or at least expect things to change on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: For the second url this works. The odd think is that the first fails...

Comment: @Rogier Yeah, servers can inspect the request and respond however they want based on what they "see". Generally, sites only want browsers to access their pages. BTW, it would be more efficient to do a HEAD request instead of GET if you just want to check if a page exists.